# How to specify the background color of the context Menu

Tags: android, menu, styles

I use a context menu in an android App to prompt the user to select a Filter.  The relevant code is:

```
TextView someView = (TextView) findViewById(id.some_view);
registerForContextMenu(someView);

...

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Select a Filter");

     menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Filter1");
     menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Filter2");
     menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Filter3");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
     if (item.getItemId() == 0)
     {
        ...
     }
     else
     {
        ...
     }
     return true;
}
```

In the styles.xml file I use the line:

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/someColor</item>
```

to set the background color of the `option Menu` items. I would like them to have the same color as the `Actionbar`. The effect is however that the `context Menu` takes on also the same color.

My question is how I can specify a background color for the `Menu` items of the `context Menu` or for the whole context Menu. Is there a way to set it individually? Could I alternatively set the background Color of the `option Menu` items on an other way without affecting the `context Menu`?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a background of `android:dropDownListViewStyle` did work for me

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.DropDownList</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.DropDownList" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:background">#f00</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately You can't customize the context menu,but you can create a `Dialog` and use that as a `ContextMenu`.something like this :

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.menu_layout);

    LinearLayout ll_menu=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_menu);

    //add some TextView or ImageView to ll_menu as menu items


    dialog.show();
}
```

menu_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/ll_menu"
     >


  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to affect dropdowns for menus you can set `android:dropDownListViewStyle`. This will handle context menus as well as the dropdown menu from the actionbar's overflow menu. I haven't looked into if this also affects `PopupMenu`s.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme that you would set in your AndroidManifest. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Theme customizations that will affect your whole application (or anywhere you apply the theme). -->
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.DropDownList</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.DropDownList" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/background_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Another option is to set the background color that is used in full screen windows across your application theme by setting `android:colorBackground` like so:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme that you would set in your AndroidManifest. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Theme customizations that will affect your whole application (or anywhere you apply the theme). -->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Check out [Android's Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#colorBackground) for more on `android:colorBackground`.